# How to get linear plateau function coefficients for nested data using FertBoot:: f.linear.plateau?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, model-fitting

I am trying to get coefficients for a quadratic, a quadratic-plateau and a linear-plateau function representing different datasets using the function f.quad, f.quad.plateau and f.linear.plateau (FertBoot-package).
When applying f.linear.plateau on the whole data set (the code I commented out in the example), it works fine, when grouping data by "group"s and nesting them instead, I get the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `LP = map(data, ~f.linear.plateau(d = .))`.  
ℹ In group 1: `group = "a"`.  
Caused by error in `map()`:  
ℹ In index: 1.  
Caused by error in `model.frame.default()`:  
! invalid type (list) for variable 'd[, 2]'  
Backtrace:
  1. df %>% group_by(group) %>% nest() %>% ...
  9. purrr::map(data, ~f.linear.plateau(d = .))
 10. purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 14. .f(.x[[i]], ...)
 15. FertBoot::f.linear.plateau(d = .)
 20. stats::model.frame.default(formula = d[, 2] ~ d[, 1], drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
```

The error doesn't appear for f.quad and f.quad.plateau.

This is the code i tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(FertBoot)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 0:200
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    a = -0.003*x^2+x+30,
    b = -0.0029*x^2+x+25,
    c = -0.004*x^2+1.2*x+20
    ) %>%
  gather(
    a,b,c, 
    key=group, 
    value = y
  ) #%>%
  #dplyr:: select(-group)

 #result <- f.linear.plateau(df)


result <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() %>%
   mutate(
     Q = map(
       data, 
       ~f.quad(d=.)
       ),
     QP = map(
       data, 
       ~f.quad.plateau(d=.)
       ),
     LP =  map(
       data, 
       ~f.linear.plateau(d=.)
     )
   )
```